# Client is not responding after an on_guild_remove event / discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Basically I have made an `on_guild_remove` Event but the Client is not responding at all. There are also no Errors. Could someone come and take a look?

**Code:**

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_guild_remove(self, guild):

         x = ""
         pfp = guild.icon_url
         embed = discord.Embed(title = x, description = "Client Broadcast System!", color = 0x456383)
         embed.add_field(name = "Type:", value = "Remove Action", inline = True)
         embed.add_field(name = "Guild's ID:", value = f"{guild.id}", inline = True)
         embed.add_field(name = "Guild's Name:", value = f"{guild}", inline = True)
         embed.add_field(name = "Guild's Member Count:", value = f"{guild.member_count}")
         embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
         embed.set_thumbnail(url=pfp)

         channel = client.get_channel(ID)
         await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

That it everything I guess. Any answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have [intents.guilds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild_remove#discord.Intents.guilds) enabled?

Comment: I did not, but I just enabled them but it still not working.

Comment: Have you enabled it **both** in your code **and** on your bot's dashboard?

Comment: Yes I have done  that  too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made only a little mistake.

Your client is self.client instead of client. (Because your class init safes the client to self.client)
So the correct code is:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_remove(self, guild):

     x = ""
     pfp = guild.icon_url
     embed = discord.Embed(title = x, description = "Client Broadcast System!", color = 0x456383)
     embed.add_field(name = "Type:", value = "Remove Action", inline = True)
     embed.add_field(name = "Guild's ID:", value = f"{guild.id}", inline = True)
     embed.add_field(name = "Guild's Name:", value = f"{guild}", inline = True)
     embed.add_field(name = "Guild's Member Count:", value = f"{guild.member_count}")
     embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
     embed.set_thumbnail(url=pfp)
     channel = self.client.get_channel(log_channel)
     await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

And a little note for other questions you ask here. You don't have to leak channel ids and other personal informations. In this case the channel id isn't too critical, so no worries!

Comment: Woah, I did not even notice that. It is weird tho because I did not get any errors as I should do. Anyways now it seems it is working. Thanks for the info. I also edited my channel ID. Thank you!